# Soften the squelch tail sound in Baofeng radio

Tags: baofeng, squelch

I have some Baofeng radios, and I set their **Squelch Tail Elimination (STE)** settings to **OFF** because I like that there's a signal when the transmitter has ended and when the receiver can start transmitting. However, the squelch squawk at the end can be very loud especially when using earphones. Is there a way to soften the volume of that squelch tail squawk?